# How to read tabular data from text file - Perl

Tags: perl

We have text file which is having data in normal as well as tabular form. i can read normal data but i am unable to read the data which is in tabular form.

Can anyone please help me out to read the and extract the tabular data.

**Text File Data :**

```
    225 Top Hitters
    RT(ms)    BRT(ms)    TL(ms)    l_mig_a    l_mig_w    b_mig_a    b_mig_w    l_b_mig_a    l_b_mig_w    b_l_mig_a    b_l_mig_w
    --------  ---------  --------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
     11078.9      141.3    3754.8        418       7325          0          0            0            4            0            4


Total active inter-cluster migrations: 0
Total wakeup inter-cluster migrations: 8
Total active migrations: 418
Total wakeup migrations: 7333
```

**My Code:**

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    my ($RT,$BRT,$TL ,$l_mig_a,$l_mig_w,$b_mig_a,$b_mig_w,$l_b_mig_a,$l_b_mig_w,$b_l_mig_a,$b_l_mig_w);
    open (FH, "<" ,"file.txt") or print "could not open $!";
    my @lines = <FH>;
    close FH;
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        print "$line \n";
    }
```

**Expected Output :**

```
$RT = 11078.9
$BRT = 141.3
$TL = 3754.8
$l_mig_a = 418
$l_mig_w = 7325
$b_mig_a = 0
$b_mig_w = 0
$l_b_mig_a = 0
$l_b_mig_w = 4
$b_l_mig_a = 0
$b_l_mig_w = 4
```

Comment: Your Perl code just prints the contents of `file.txt`. How can the output possibly look like your *“Expected Output”*? The problem seems to be that you haven't troubled yourself to try anything, and that's not something we can help you with

Comment: If you had searched this site for **30 seconds** before asking this question, you would have found something close enough to what you need. I mean, you'd have to insert your own data, but I would think you'd be able to manage that.

Comment: And you're not "unable to read the data which is in tabular form". You can _read_ it just fine! You just don't know how to [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) it out into separate fields. Oops... now I guess you do.

Comment: So, does your file really only have 10 lines, or does the values row repeat a number of times?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can "slurp" whole file into single string variable and use regular expression to parse tabular data. Below please find sample script with subroutine to simplify generating regular expression.

Below please find sample implementation with test data bundled with code into single script/file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text;
{
  # put all lines into single string
  local $/ = undef;
  $text = <DATA>;
}

my $regex = &make_regex(qw{RT(ms)    BRT(ms)    TL(ms)    l_mig_a    l_mig_w    b_mig_a    b_mig_w    l_b_mig_a    l_b_mig_w    b_l_mig_a    b_l_mig_w});

print "REGEX-START\n$regex\nREGEX-END\n"; # Debuging: Show generated regular expression

my ($RT,$BRT,$TL ,$l_mig_a,$l_mig_w,$b_mig_a,$b_mig_w,$l_b_mig_a,$l_b_mig_w,$b_l_mig_a,$b_l_mig_w) 
   = $text =~ /$regex/ or die;

print "b_l_mig_w = $b_l_mig_w\n";

sub make_regex {
  my $n = scalar(@_);
  my $str = '
\s*' . join('\s+',map {quotemeta($_)} @_) . '\s*
\s*' . join('\s+',('-+')    x $n) . '\s*
\s*' . join('\s+',('(\S+)') x $n) . '\s*
';
  qr{$str}m;
} # end sub make_regex

__DATA__
    225 Top Hitters
    RT(ms)    BRT(ms)    TL(ms)    l_mig_a    l_mig_w    b_mig_a    b_mig_w    l_b_mig_a    l_b_mig_w    b_l_mig_a    b_l_mig_w
    --------  ---------  --------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
     11078.9      141.3    3754.8        418       7325          0          0            0            4            0            4


Total active inter-cluster migrations: 0
Total wakeup inter-cluster migrations: 8
Total active migrations: 418
Total wakeup migrations: 733
```

Comment: That's a horribly over-engineered piece of code

Comment: @Borodin Feel free to offer your "simple to use" alternative.  I am ready to learn.

Comment: It depends on the consistency of the data, as yours does, but `my @fields = split if $. == 4` should do fine

Comment: My assumptions about "text format stability" were quite different than yours.  I am not inclined to assume that 1) we received FULL text file 2) there is no need to extract OTHER "tabular data" with different columns. **We** may only guess whose guesses are better.  Based on your assumptions my solution is worse. Based on my assumptions it is better IMHO.  Do you know the text file format in the query?

Comment: No, I don't. But the solution is to *ask the OP* rather than write a massive amount of code that may still not do what is required. If my guess is correct then the OP has adopted a crazy, unreadable solution that no one will be able to re-use

Comment: I would have to agree with @Borodin here. This answer seems like overkill (and probably went way over the head of the person who asked the question).

Comment: **So far** the answer stays as accepted. Anyway the "over-engineered overkill" may be used to merely generate initial version of the regular expression.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip No offense, but accepted doesn't automatically mean good.

Comment: @MattJacob **The asker** is the most important judge.  **So far** it makes be believe that my guesses about "hidden assumptions" are better.  I am ready and willing to confirm that different set of "hidden assumptions" can make my code look "over-engineered  over-kill" with ease. P.S. Anyway I needed some exercises in making scripts generate regular expressions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In your expected output, you include a `$` before each header name. I *hope* your intent isn't to `eval` the results and use the values programmatically, because there are better ways to do that (e.g., a hash). If that was your plan, you're also missing semicolons at the end of the lines.

Since I can't infer your use case from your question, I decided to simply dump the keys and values as-is; feel free to add whatever embellishments you'd like.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @keys;
my @values;

while (<DATA>) {
    if ($. == 2) {
        @keys = split;

        for (@keys) {
            s/\W.+$//;
        }

    } elsif ($. == 4) {
        @values = split;
        last;
    }
}

for my $i (0 .. $#keys) {
    print "$keys[$i] = $values[$i]\n";
}


__DATA__
225 Top Hitters
RT(ms)    BRT(ms)    TL(ms)    l_mig_a    l_mig_w    b_mig_a    b_mig_w    l_b_mig_a    l_b_mig_w    b_l_mig_a    b_l_mig_w
--------  ---------  --------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
 11078.9      141.3    3754.8        418       7325          0          0            0            4            0            4


Total active inter-cluster migrations: 0
Total wakeup inter-cluster migrations: 8
Total active migrations: 418
Total wakeup migrations: 7333
```

If your input file is really only 10 lines long (i.e., there aren't an additional 5 million data rows you haven't told us about), you could simplify the reading and splitting to a few lines of code:

```
my @lines  = <DATA>;
my @keys   = map { s/\W.+$//r } split(' ', $lines[1]);
my @values = split(' ', $lines[3]);
```

Output:

```
RT = 11078.9
BRT = 141.3
TL = 3754.8
l_mig_a = 418
l_mig_w = 7325
b_mig_a = 0
b_mig_w = 0
l_b_mig_a = 0
l_b_mig_w = 4
b_l_mig_a = 0
b_l_mig_w = 4
```

To collect the values for later use in your program while maintaining the association between the headers and the values, create a hash:

```
my %hash;
@hash{@keys} = @values;
```

The hash will have the following structure:

```
{
  b_l_mig_a => 0,
  b_l_mig_w => 4,
  b_mig_a => 0,
  b_mig_w => 0,
  BRT => 141.3,
  l_b_mig_a => 0,
  l_b_mig_w => 4,
  l_mig_a => 418,
  l_mig_w => 7325,
  RT => 11078.9,
  TL => 3754.8,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative strategy to Matt's, which searches for the first line in the file that contains one or more hyphens `-`, possible whitespace, and nothing else. Then the column labels are on the previous line and the values on the following line

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'max';

use constant DATA_FILE => 'tabular_data.txt';

# Read the whole file into an array

my @file = do {
    open my $fh, '<', DATA_FILE or die $!;
    <$fh>;
};
chomp @file;

# Find the first line that contains only one or more hyphens
# and possibly some whitespace

my $i = 0;
for ( @file ) {
    last if /\-/ and not /[^-\s]/;
    ++$i;
}

die "Header line not found" unless $i < @file;

# Build the key array from the preceding line, and the
# values array from the succeeding line

my @keys = split ' ', $file[$i-1];
s/\(.*// for @keys;

my @values = split ' ', $file[$i+1];

my %data;
@data{@keys} = @values;

# Display what we've recovered

my $w = max map length, @keys;

for my $key ( @keys ) {
    printf "%-*s => %s\n", $w, $key, $data{$key};
}
```

#### output

```
RT        => 11078.9
BRT       => 141.3
TL        => 3754.8
l_mig_a   => 418
l_mig_w   => 7325
b_mig_a   => 0
b_mig_w   => 0
l_b_mig_a => 0
l_b_mig_w => 4
b_l_mig_a => 0
b_l_mig_w => 4
```

Comment: Accidental double post?

Comment: @MattJacob: Thanks. Yes, this happens from time to time and it's either a bug in Windows Firefox *and* Android Chrome or it's an issue with Stack Overflow's server. I certainly didn't click on `Add Another Answer` so there's no way this should have happened. I think the two posts are identical but I need to check before I delete one

Comment: @MattJacob: They were *both* old copies of the code. Thanks for alerting me